# Net use - error 53 encountered when using c$ but not c$\subfolder

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, network-shares, net-use

When I run this piece of code in Powershell:

```
net use \\$computerName\c$\ $adminPW /user:$adminUN /Persistent:No
```

I get:

```
System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
```

However, if I run:

```
net use \\$computerName\c$\subfolder $adminPW /user:$adminUN /Persistent:No
```

It executes successfully assuming `subfolder` exists. Why is this happening? I am running this code in order to eventually create a folder within `c$`, maybe there is an alternative method?

Comment: Try as `net use \\$computerName\c$ $adminPW /user:$adminUN /Persistent:No` and remove that backslash from the `c$\\` if you are trying to map to the root of the hidden "C" share

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I could have sworn I had tried that but guess not :)

Comment: You could omit the whole `c$\\` really, since Windows stores credentials per-host anyway (not per-share).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a simple syntax issue when using the [net use](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) command to map to the hidden `C$` share that you can easily correct by omitting the trailing backslash from the `C$` path.

**Correct syntax to map to hidden admin shares**

```
net use \\$computerName\c$ $adminPW /user:$adminUN /Persistent:No
```

**Note:** *You will want to omit the trailing backslash from the `\\$computerName\c$\` path and just use `\\$computerName\c$` just like that without the final backslash.*

---

### Further Resources

- [NET USE](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html)
- [Administrative Share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share)